# Updating all screen activities by one single click

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My problem is how to update all other activity by 1 click.For example I have `3 screen` `Activity` named `MainActivity`,`FirstActivity`,`SecondActivity`.In each of the `activity` ,have 1 `textview`.

Button onclick is in `MainActivity`.When button click,all textview in each activity will display  a text.....

Comment: You can use observer pattern for this [click here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `shared preferences`. Just put an entry in shared preference when the button is clicked. Like this:

```
 Button btnCancel = userDataDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
 btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(key, "sampleText");
            editor.commit();
        }
 });
```

And in all other activites, you can retrieve the `sampleText` from shared preference and show in the `textview`.

Comment: Much better than my answer. Although, one can use an observer pattern to accomplish this, no?

Comment: yes,I forgot we can use share preferences. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an observer design pattern for this, a ‘one to many’ relationship. What you are asking requires more code than I am willing to put here, but this is a useful link to get started:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_BpmfnqjgzQ

Comment: this is a new things for me.might check it out.anyway Thanks.